# How to create a Python wrapper for a DLL library

Tags: python, windows, dll, wrapper, ctypes

I am trying to take a provided DLL file from a software SDK and create a python wrapper so to integrate it with the rest of my code base. I have followed quite a few guides online, and still having no luck.

The current Python code I have is:

```py
from ctypes import *
from ctypes.wintypes import HWND
import os

class OptistarDLL(object):
    dll_path = 'OSDS142MRT.dll'

    with open(dll_path) as thefile:
        pass

    _dll = WinDLL(dll_path)

    init_library = _dll['OSDS142M_Initialize']
    init_library.restype = c_int
    init_library.argtypes = (c_int, c_bool, HWND, c_bool, c_int)


class OpticstarControl(object):
    
    def __init__(self):
        err = OptistarDLL.init_library(c_int(0), c_bool(False), HWND(0), c_bool(False), c_int(0))
        if err != 0:
            raise Exception("Doom")
```

The SDK documentation I am using provides this as the header for the function:

```cpp
DLLDIR int OSDS142M_Initialize(int iModel, bool bOutVid, HWND hwOutVid, bool bStarView, int iRt);
```

And the example PDF gives:

```
OSDS142M_Initialize(1, false, 0, true, 0);
```

Initialisation currently gets me only

```
ValueError: Procedure probably called with too many arguments (20 bytes in excess)
```

I have read, but not understood, about the `WinDLL` vs `CDLL`, and the loading of the DLL fails when I change to `CDLL`. I have also seen in all the guides that the headers in them have `DLLEXPORT` and mine has `DLLDIR`, and I don't know if this is a concern.

Does anyone have any ideas?

---

[<sup>ctypes documentation</sup>](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html)

[<sup>WinDLL examples</sup>](https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/59464/ctypes.WinDLL)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most likely explanation, given the information in the question, is that the DLL uses `cdecl` rather than `stdcall`. Your use of `WinDLL` matches a `stdcall` DLL. Use `CDLL` instead to switch to `cdecl` calling convention.

The error message is consistent with this. The difference between the calling conventions is that `stdcall` has callee stack cleanup and `cdecl` has caller clean up. The parameters consume 20 bytes on the stack, being 5 parameters all of size 4. And ctypes pushed those parameters on and expected the callee to clean up the stack. Which it not do because it's a `cdecl` function.

Your call to the function is needlessly complex. You can write:

```
err = OptistarDLL.init_library(0, False, 0, False, 0)
```

Note that the example call that you quote passes different parameters. To match that call you would write:

```
err = OptistarDLL.init_library(1, False, 0, True, 0)
```

You should certainly remove this code:

```
with open(dll_path) as thefile:
    pass
```

That serves no purpose other than to waste time. If the DLL does not exist, you will encounter failure soon enough.

Comment: Hi David, when trying to call via the `CDLL`, I get a return code of 13. It does however appear that instantiation didn't fail in the same way as it did with the `WinDLL`, in the sense that the method was actually invoked. I therefore assume this is probably a library issue now, and so I will take it up with Opticstar.

Comment: Yes. Return code of 13 sounds like thee interop is now correct.